# On saving a new record an associated id changes to 9 figure number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a table of venues, with each venue belonging to an area and a type. I recently dropped the table and added to it some addressline fields. I have re-migrated it but now the area_id field saves as a random? 9 figure number. Both the area_id and venuetype_id integers are created in the same way from the create new form and the venuetype_id saves as normal but not the area_id. Can anyone offer any help?

**whats shown in the console**

```
=> [#<Venue id: 4, name: "sdf", addressline1: "", addressline2: "", addressline3
: "", addressline4: "", icontoppx: 234, iconleftpx: 234, area_id: 946717224, ven
uetype_id: 8, created_at: "2011-03-17", updated_at: "2011-03-17 23:33:53">]
irb(main):030:0>
```

the area_id should be 8 in the above example.

The area and venuetype id's are slected from dropdown boxes on the new venue form.

**new form**

```
<%= form_for @venue do |f| %>
  <p>name: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

  <p>top: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :icontoppx %></p>

  <p>left: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :iconleftpx %></p>

  <p>addressline1: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :addressline1 %></p>

  <p>addressline2: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :addressline2 %></p>

  <p>addressline3: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :addressline3 %></p>

  <p>addressline4: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :addressline4 %></p>

  <p>area: <br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:area_id, Area.all, :id, :name) %></p>

  <p>venuetype: <br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:venuetype_id, Venuetype.all, :id, :name) %></p>

  <br><br>

  <div class="button"><%= submit_tag %></div>
<% end %>
```

**Areas table**

```
class CreateAreas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :areas do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :areas
  end
end
```

**Area records shown from console**

```
irb(main):001:0> Area.all
=> [#<Area id: 8, name: "Area1", created_at: "2011-03-17 23:28:40", u
pdated_at: "2011-03-17 23:28:40">, #<Area id: 9, name: "Area2", created_at:
"2011-03-17 23:29:50", updated_at: "2011-03-17 23:29:50">]
irb(main):002:0> Area.all.map(&:id)
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: @Gabe, Both Area and Venuetypes contain just an ID and name fields

Comment: Does your Venue class have belongs_to :area? What happens if you do Area.all.map(&:id) in the console?

Comment: @Kyle, thanks for having a look, yea the relationships are all set properly before I added the new fields it worked fine I'll try what you mentioned when I get home, I'm thinking I'll try dropping all the tables and re migrating like the good old turn it off and on again method.

Comment: @Kyle, I've added into my question the Area records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem presented in a few ways, including changing the updated at field to a bigdecimal. Anyway, I'm no expert but I think its a blip with windows and mysql2 it corrected by copy pasting a new copy of the libmySQL.dll from the mysql bin directory to the ruby bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

The long integer is the internal ruby object id. I'm guessing the things Area.all is returning are not ActiveRecord objects. Could this be the case?

Does the area select list options look correct in the browser and in the source? I expect you're seeing the 9 digit values in the source.

Comment: The dropdown in the create new venue form displays the names of the areas correctly but once saved it redirects to the venues index page and gives a undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #5): with line 5 being: <span class="venue_partial_area_name"><%= venue.area.name %></span>